# Angular - model method called in template is executed in endless loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

In my angular app, I have model class defined:

```
import {Type} from "class-transformer"; //https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer

export class Case {
  id: string;

  @Type(() => Date)
  created: string;
  status: string;

  get customMethod() {
    return `Hello ${this.id}`;
  }

  isPending() {
    console.log('isPending() called...');
    return this.status == 'new';
  }

}
```

In my component, I fetching cases from rest api:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.api.getCases().subscribe((cases) => {
      this.cases = cases;
    });
  }
```

and getCases() looks like:

```
import {plainToClass} from "class-transformer";
import {Case} from "../models/Case";

// ... come other code

  public getCases() {
    return this.http.get(`${this.apiUrl}/cases`).pipe(map(response => {
      return plainToClass(Case, response as Case[])
    }))

  }
```

It works fine, in my component I get Case instances. I am passing these instances to other child components:

```
<app-case-listing [case]="case" *ngFor="let case of cases"></app-case-listing>
```

and that child component template is just:

```
<li [class.pending]="case.isPending()">
  li element for case {{case.customMethod}}, {{case.status}}
</li>
```

Everythink works almost fine - except that isPending() seems to be called in a loop. I am not sure if it is an expected behaviour or not (or if is it good in terms of performance). When I add console log to "customMethod" getter its also logs in loop.

Console output looks like (thousands of such messages):

```
isPending() called...
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
zone.js:2279 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 168ms
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
zone.js:2279 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 185ms
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
zone.js:2279 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 186ms
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
6
breadcrumbs.js:58 isPending() called...
zone.js:2279 [Violation] 'setTimeout' handler took 197ms
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is it a proper behaviour?
2. If not - how can I fix/optimize my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's proper behaviour, you call a `isPending` method inside of `ngFor` loop, and the method calls for each `Case` instance. You can add ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, to `app-case-listing` component for avoid uneccessary checks.